# Bootstrap - Add Triangle Indicator on Active btn-check

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 5 app. In this app, I have three *different* sized buttons in a group. The button group is defined like this:

```
<div class="btn-group d-flex">
  <button class="btn btn-info py-4">Sunday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info py-4">Monday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info py-4">Tuesday</button>
</div>
```

When I select one of the buttons, I can see that the following CSS classes get applied:

```
.btn-check:focus + .btn-info, .btn-info:focus
```

When a user selects one of the buttons, I would like to apply a centered "triangle" on the button. My question is, how do I add a *centered* triangle indicator on a button with the focus?

To demonstrate, at this time, my buttons look like this:

```
+-------------+
| Day of Week |
+-------------+
```

However, I when a button is selected, I want them to look like this:

```
+------^------+
| Day of Week |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

I just used an after on the button which adds the arrow up.

```css
.btn-info{
  

    border-top:1px dashed black;
      border-bottom:1px dashed black;
      border-right:1px dotted black;
      border-left:1px dotted black;
      position:relative;
      z-index:0;
      background-color:white;
padding:5px;
}
.btn-info:focus-within::after{
  content:'^';
  position:absolute;
  height:5px;
  width:5px;
  bottom:100%;
  left:50%;
  background:white;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group d-flex">
  <button class="btn btn-info py-4">Sunday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info py-4">Monday</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info py-4">Tuesday</button>
</div>
```